# grails populate controller model from bootstrap.groovy without database support

Tags: grails, grails-controller

I understand that the standard way to use bootstrap.groovy and a controller is to create the data and save them to DB in the bootstrap init()
The controller can then read the data, so the "middle man" between the two is the database.

But, what if I want to create data in bootstrap.groovy and not save them in the database (let's assume these data don't need to be saved), how can I inject the data into the controller so they could be used for views rendering ?

Let's take a simple example with a domain class Book. Simply in bootstrap I just want to crete a dummy list of 100 books:

```
class BootStrap {

    def grailsApplication

    def List<Book> books

    def init = { servletContext ->
        books = new ArrayList<>()

        for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
            books.add(new Book(numPages: 20))
        }

    }

    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

The goal is now to expose/inject he list of books to a BookController.
How would I do that? I could not find a simple way or an answer anywhere about this

Answer (score 0):

Services are singleton in Grails by default, so you could store that data in a service. But you have to be careful, because a service could be used concurrently.

https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/services.html

Comment: That sounds like a possible solution, but then I would assume the service instance is available (already initialized) within the controller and not bootstrap.groovy. That could be ok if you need to call a lightweight method within the service, but if I need to call a method within the service that does I/O operation (reading a json file in this case) I would think a place like bootstrap.groovy is the best place to do that (during application boot up) and once the data have been cached services and controllers can start to use them

Comment: There are many correct approachs for solving your problem and of course will be depending on you. It's up to you how to do it, at least for me all are correct. You could also check on the service if the data has been loaded (on demand), and if not load the data and save it on memory.

Answer (score 0):

To generalize the problem I have posted above (after reading the answer from quindimildev) generally every framework should have a way to perform initialization operations ... such as initializing a cache from a file or database or 3rd party services. By the time the application has started those data are in memory ready to be used by controllers, etc...

The typical applications/examples I have seen for grails don't take this into consideration, and they assume your database is populated and read through controllers actions. This is fine for most applications, but I would be surprise if grails doesn't provide a mechanism to build a cache at start up (one time operation that could take a few seconds) that can be available to all controllers once the application has started.

I hope this clarifies the scenario I am trying to address